# Countdown AppIndicator

Tags: beginner, ruby, linux, timer

I've decided to translate an old Unity AppIndicator I had written in C to Ruby, so I can practice coding with it (got a little bored with the completely beginner lessons I've been following, which I'll finish!). The C indicator itself was a bit raw, I kind of wrote it in an afternoon, so I think it reflected on the Ruby indicator as well.

It's still a work in progress. For now the timer can be configured only through a configuration file (which is described in the README and in the example file). Once the file is set, the user can start the indicator, click on the icon, "Start timer..." and "Get from config file". The reason this window pops up is because I was thinking about making a more friendly UI where the user could input the same parameters.

There are 4 parameters you can configure: Enable Notify and Notify Delay (issues `notify-send` calls to remind the user of how much time is left), Initial timer and Persistent timer (the former just sets at how many seconds will the timer start at and the latter will make the timer persistent once you close and open the app again). The persistent timer works by writing a file which has the epoch time when the timer is supposed to end, so it can resume.

The icon color of the indicator changes in some ranges (over 10 minutes it is blue, over 5 minutes it's orange, below 5 minutes it's red and when it reaches 0 it's black). Once it reaches 0, nothing happens (I plan to implement some notification, maybe an alarm).

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/IanCaio/Ruby-CountdownI)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'ruby-libappindicator'

# DEBUG FUNCTION
DEBUG=true
def debug(message)
    if DEBUG==true
        puts "DEBUG: "+message
    end
end

# SOME CONSTANTS
BLUE_ICON_RANGE = 600       #10 minutes
ORANGE_ICON_RANGE = 300     #5 minutes
# So here is how it goes: Timer > 10 minutes icon is blue. 10 minutes > Timer > 5 minutes icon is orange. Timer < 5 minutes
# icon is red. Timer is 0 icon is black.

# MAIN CLASS
class CountdownI_Class < AppIndicator::AppIndicator
    # Class variables
    @notify_delay       #Delay between the timer notifications
    @enable_notify      #Enable notifications?
    @persistent_timer   #Should the timer be persistent between calls? (Keeping track of the same timer every time you launch)

    @target_timer       #The epoch time where the timer will be over
    @countdown_timer    #The seconds remaining

    @indicator_icons    #Array with the different paths to the icons the indicator will use

    @is_running = false #Did we start the timer?

    # Initialization (Set the indicator and the default variables values)
    def initialize(name, icon, category)
        super

        #Gtk + AppIndicator Setup
        #Getting icons paths
        @indicator_icons = []
        @indicator_icons[0] = File.realpath("./Icons/IconBlack.png")
        @indicator_icons[1] = File.realpath("./Icons/IconBlue.png")
        @indicator_icons[2] = File.realpath("./Icons/IconOrange.png")
        @indicator_icons[3] = File.realpath("./Icons/IconRed.png")

        mainmenu = Gtk::Menu.new

        #Start the timer
        mainmenu_start = Gtk::MenuItem.new("Start timer...")
        mainmenu_start.signal_connect("activate"){
            #We parse the mainmenu_start menu item as an argument because if we start the counter
            #we need to disable this item.
            self.start_timer(mainmenu_start)
        }

        mainmenu.append(mainmenu_start)
        mainmenu_start.show()

        #Quit
        mainmenu_quit = Gtk::MenuItem.new("Quit")
        mainmenu_quit.signal_connect("activate"){
            self.quit_timer()
        }

        mainmenu.append(mainmenu_quit)
        mainmenu_quit.show()

        set_menu(mainmenu)
        set_status(AppIndicator::Status::ACTIVE)

        #Default variables values
        @notify_delay=300
        @enable_notify=false
        @countdown_timer=30
        @persistent_timer=false
    end

    # Read the configuration file if it's present and readable (if it isn't present creates the default one)
    def read_config()
        #Checks if configuration file exists and if it's readable. If it doesn't exist, write one with default
        #values. If it does exist but isn't readable, leave it there and use default values. Else, just use the
        #values from the file.
        if(File.exists?(File.realpath("./Config")+"/CountdownI.config"))
            debug("Config file exists!")
            if(File.readable?(File.realpath("./Config/CountdownI.config")))
                debug("Config file is readable!")
                debug("Reading:")
                config_file = File.open(File.realpath("./Config/CountdownI.config"),"r")

                while(line = config_file.gets)
                    if(!line.start_with?("//") && line.chomp.length>0)
                        param_value_list = line.split("=")
                        debug("Parameter: #{param_value_list[0]} - Value: #{param_value_list[1]}")

                        case param_value_list[0]
                            when "NOTIFY DELAY"
                                @notify_delay=param_value_list[1].to_i
                            when "ENABLE NOTIFY"
                                if(param_value_list[1].chomp == "TRUE")
                                    @enable_notify=true
                                else
                                    @enable_notify=false
                                end
                            when "INITIAL TIMER"
                                @countdown_timer=param_value_list[1].to_i
                            when "PERSISTENT TIMER"
                                if(param_value_list[1].chomp == "TRUE")
                                    @persistent_timer=true
                                else
                                    @persistent_timer=false
                                end
                        end
                    end
                end
                config_file.close
            else
                debug("Config file not readable. Using default values...")
            end
        else
            debug("Config file not present. Writing the default one...")
            config_file = File.open(File.realpath("./Config")+"/CountdownI.config","w")

            # Write default configuration file
            config_file.write("//The configuration file is simple:\n//NOTIFY DELAY=<number> being number in the range 60-1200 seconds\n//ENABLE NOTIFY=TRUE/FALSE anything other than that means false.\n//INITIAL TIMER=<number> the initial countdown timer\n//PERSISTENT TIMER=TRUE/FALSE anything other than that means false.\n\nNOTIFY DELAY=300\nENABLE NOTIFY=FALSE\nINITIAL TIMER=30\nPERSISTENT TIMER=FALSE\n")

            config_file.close
        end

        # Check the values and use default ones if anything is odd:
        if(@notify_delay < 60 || @notify_delay > 1200)
            @notify_delay = 300
        end
        if(@countdown_timer <= 0)
            @countdown_timer = 30
        end
    end

    def set_timer()
        debug("Current epoch time = "+Time.new.strftime("%s"))

        # If the timer is not persistent, just calculate the target timer from the current epoch time
        if(@persistent_timer == false)
            debug("Persistent timer is Off!")

            @target_timer = Time.new.to_i + @countdown_timer

            debug("Countdown timer = "+@countdown_timer.to_s)
            debug("Target timer = "+@target_timer.to_s)
        else
        # If the timer is persistent, we check the target timer from the restore file if it exists or create one if it doesn't
            debug("Persistent timer is On!")
            debug("Restore file path: "+File.realpath("./")+"/countdown.restore")

            # File is there, we just restore the target timer
            if(File.exists?(File.realpath("./")+"/countdown.restore"))
                debug("Restore file is present")
                if(File.readable?(File.realpath("./")+"/countdown.restore"))
                    debug("Restore file is readable")

                    restore_file = File.open(File.realpath("./countdown.restore"),"r")

                    while(line = restore_file.gets)
                        @target_timer = line.to_i
                    end

                    @countdown_timer = @target_timer - Time.new.to_i

                    debug("Target timer from restore file = "+@target_timer.to_s)
                    debug("Countdown timer = "+@countdown_timer.to_s)

                    restore_file.close
                else
                    #This error shouldn't happen if the user didn't play around with chmod/chown...
                    puts("[ERROR]: You don't have permissions to read the restore file...")
                    exit(1)
                end
            else
            # File isn't there, we should create it
                debug("Restore file not present!")

                @target_timer = Time.new.to_i + @countdown_timer

                debug("Countdown timer = "+@countdown_timer.to_s)
                debug("Target timer = "+@target_timer.to_s)

                # Effectively writes the restore file
                self.write_restore_file
            end
        end
    end

    def write_restore_file()
        debug("Writing restore file:")
        if(File.exists?(File.realpath("./")+"/countdown.restore"))
            debug("Restore file exists already")
            if(File.writable?(File.realpath("./")+"/countdown.restore"))
                debug("Restore file is writable")

                restore_file = File.open(File.realpath("./countdown.restore"),"w")

                restore_file.write(@target_timer.to_s)

                restore_file.close
            else
                #This error shouldn't happen if the user didn't play around with chmod/chown...
                puts("[ERROR]: You don't have permissions to write to the restore file...")
                exit(1)
            end
        else
            debug("Restore file doesn't exist. Writing it...")

            restore_file = File.open(File.realpath("./")+"/countdown.restore","w")

            restore_file.write(@target_timer.to_s)

            restore_file.close
        end
    end

    def remove_restore_file()
        debug("Removing restore file:")
        if(File.exists?(File.realpath("./")+"/countdown.restore"))
            debug("Restore file is present")
            if(File.writable?(File.realpath("./")+"/countdown.restore"))
                debug("Restore file is writable, so probably deletable too")
                debug("Deleting restore file...")

                File.delete(File.realpath("./countdown.restore"))
            else
                #This error shouldn't happen if the user didn't play around with chmod/chown...
                puts("[ERROR]: You don't have write permissions to the restore file...")
                exit(1)
            end
        else
            debug("Restore file is not present. Not deleting anything")
        end
    end

    def update_timer()
        @countdown_timer = @target_timer - Time.new.to_i

        if(@countdown_timer < 0)
            @countdown_timer = 0
        end

        if(@countdown_timer > BLUE_ICON_RANGE)
            self.set_icon(@indicator_icons[1])
        elsif(@countdown_timer > ORANGE_ICON_RANGE)
            self.set_icon(@indicator_icons[2])
        elsif(@countdown_timer > 0)
            self.set_icon(@indicator_icons[3])
        else
            self.set_icon(@indicator_icons[0])
        end
    end

    def start_timer(caller_menuitem)
        #We will display a window where the user can set the timer
        #or choose to get the parameters from the config file.

        start_window = Gtk::Window.new()
        start_window.set_border_width(10)

        start_from_config_btn = Gtk::Button.new("Get from config file")
        start_from_config_btn.signal_connect("clicked"){
            #Read the configuration file and set the parameters
            self.read_config()

            debug("VALUES: ")
            debug('Enable notify: '+@enable_notify.to_s)
            debug('Notify delay: '+@notify_delay.to_s)
            debug('Initial timer: '+@countdown_timer.to_s)
            debug('Persistent timer: '+@persistent_timer.to_s)

            debug("Setting timer:")

            #Set the timer
            self.set_timer()

            #Timeout function that will update the indicator
            GLib::Timeout.add(1000){
                self.update_timer()

                self.set_label("Time left: "+@countdown_timer.to_s+" seconds", "CountdownI")

                true
            }

            #Timeout function that will issue the 'notify-send' commands
            if(@enable_notify)
                GLib::Timeout.add(@notify_delay*1000){
                    debug("Notify timeout!")

                    if(@countdown_timer > BLUE_ICON_RANGE)
                        Kernel::system("notify-send --icon='"+@indicator_icons[1]+"' 'CountdownI: "+@countdown_timer.to_s+" seconds left!'")
                    elsif(@countdown_timer > ORANGE_ICON_RANGE)
                        Kernel::system("notify-send --icon='"+@indicator_icons[2]+"' 'CountdownI: "+@countdown_timer.to_s+" seconds left!'")
                    elsif(@countdown_timer > 0)
                        Kernel::system("notify-send --icon='"+@indicator_icons[3]+"' 'CountdownI: "+@countdown_timer.to_s+" seconds left!'")
                    end

                    #I don't think we can use "return" here... Maybe because it's not a function, but a block of code?
                    if(@countdown_timer <= 0)
                        false
                    else
                        true
                    end
                }
            end

            @is_running = true

            start_window.destroy()

            #The menuitem from the indicator is now inactive
            caller_menuitem.set_sensitive(false)
        }

        start_window.add(start_from_config_btn)

        start_window.show_all
    end

    def quit_timer()
        #If we didn't start the timer yet, we don't need to bother with the restore file
        if(@is_running == true)
            #If the time is up, we are in the persistent mode and there is a restore file, remove it...
            if(CountdownI.instance_variable_get("@persistent_timer") && CountdownI.instance_variable_get("@countdown_timer")<=0)
                CountdownI.remove_restore_file()
            end
        end

        Gtk.main_quit()
    end
end

# Program flow

Gtk.init()

#Create the indicator object
CountdownI = CountdownI_Class.new("CountdownI", File.realpath("./Icons/IconBlack.png"), AppIndicator::Category::APPLICATION_STATUS)

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: If I have time, I might be able to submit something.. but my first suggestion would be to look into object oriented programming. Here is something to get you started: http://tutorials.codebar.io/ruby/lesson4/tutorial.html

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: Thanks @Mat'sMug, I wasn't aware of this rule. I'll check if it's worth writing another question about this code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many places you can improve the code, and it is tempting to rewrite large chunks of it because it will warrant a rewrite to fit in with Ruby standards and idioms.

#### basic style

I would suggest you read through the [ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), and fix up those simple things - indentation, method calls (no need for empty '()'), spacing, single quotes vs double quotes, parens around conditionals etc.

#### Think in objects

It's clear you are coming from a more procedural language, but you have to unlearn those habits and learn new object-oriented approaches to your code design.

You have a single object, but this program definitely deserves at least a few more objects. I would suggest you look through [design pattern examples](https://github.com/nslocum/design-patterns-in-ruby) and perhaps buy the accompanying book.

If your code was logically broken down into different objects that had meaningful relationships and clearly defined responsibilities, it would be much easier to read it from afar and maintain it in the future.

#### Break up your object

..into other objects and/or small methods.

Generally, you should be doing as little processing in your initialize method as possible. Initializing a class should not kick off a bunch of stuff to create this God Object. A simple, temporary solution to this would be to move out everything you can into a separate method, aptly named.

Something like:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(name, item, category)
    @name, @item, @category = name, item, category
    # very minimal processing - set variables, etc, that's it
  end

  def self.build(name, item, category)
    new(name, item, category).build
  end

  def build
    # throw bulk initialization processing in here
  end
end

# usage
MyClass.build(name, item, category)
```

While you are moving your initializing code, think about breaking it up into smaller, descriptive methods.

For example, you could extract your `@indicator_icons` into a method..

```
def indicator_icons
  @indicator_icons ||= begin
    [
      File.realpath("./Icons/IconBlack.png"),
      File.realpath("./Icons/IconBlue.png"),
      ...
    ]
  end
end
```

Can't comment much on the menu object as it's a little difficult to read. One thing I will say it looks like you're weaving in and out of class and object contexts (use of `self` in initialize). Be wary of this.

#### fix your attributes

The way you are specifying attributes is wrong, and actually shouldn't have an effect at all. If you want to define attributes and a way to access or modify them, you can use either `attr_reader :list, :of, :attributes` or `attr_writer :list, :of, :attributes` or, for both `attr_accessor :list, :of, :attributes`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) for more info.

#### extract more!

Another prime opportunity for extraction is your config file parsing. If you can use a different format that doesn't require so much parsing (yaml, etc), great! If not, you should look into extracting the parser into its own object.

You would then have something like (note no empty `()`):

```
def config
  @config ||= Config.parse('CountdownI.config')
end
```

Couple of other notes on the above code. I've removed `read_` as that is redundant. In Ruby, we forget about `read_` this, `get_` that, `is_` this, `set_` that. Be succinct and descriptive. The method name clearly indicates it will return your config.

I have also used [memoization](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/) (`@config ||=`). This is to prevent the method from parsing the config multiple times. It will parse once and set variable as return of parse, then simply return variable value on subsequent calls. Get used to this and use it for making your code more efficient.

#### extract yet more!

Another opportunity for extraction is in your conditionals.

You have: `if(@enable_notify)`

First, as noted in the basic style part of this review, you shouldn't use parentheses. It should be `if @enable_notify`. Better yet, you can extract this into a [predicate method](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/objects/predicates.html):

```
def notify?
  @enable_notify
end

if notify?
  ...
end
```

#### in closing

The main issues I would say:

- basic syntax/ruby style is off - read style guides
- single object is doing too much - break out responsibilities into other objects
- breakdown objects into small, descriptive methods

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm struggling a little to adapt my programming from procedural to OOP. I'd use `structs` on C, but nothing compared to the design most OO codes have. I also think I stuck myself with the style I used when coding in C. I'll edit to make it fit the Ruby Style, so I can get used to it (it conflicts a bit with the style I try to follow on C, but I need to face the fact I'm learning a different language and should think like a Rubyst when writing in Ruby!). Also, I'll try to follow your guidelines on the OOP aproach. Do you think it's better if I start the code from scratch?

Comment: @IanC it's understandable how you've approached the problem. To answer your question, I think it would be a great idea to first read through those posts I linked to and then rewrite it from scratch with a different mindset. You will definitely learn something considerable that way.

Comment: @IanC one other pointer about objects - when I say use objects, I don't mean throw everything into class-level methods. I mean using instantiating actual objects. This allows you much more power over the behaviour and helps to better encapsulate it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll read through all the links and suggestions and will start over the indicator (reusing some snippets only, but rethinking the code design) and once I have something I'll get back with the updated code! By the way, I'm not sure I understood your last comment. Do you mean that I should avoid making multiple classes but actually instantiating just a few objects? Should I avoid inheritance then?

Comment: @IanC what I mean by instantiating objects, is try to refrain from what might be your inclination to hide your logic in a bunch of class-level methods and, as a result, not make use of proper objects. Still separate into different classes and use inheritance if it makes sense, but don't just throw everything into a class-level method/function. See [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) for more info on the difference. I'm sure you know what I mean, that's just for clarification in case I've not explained too well ;)

Comment: @IanC when you do update the code, it might be worth keeping your current version around for reference sake, and so it doesn't invalidate my review. I can always append further feedback onto the review.

Comment: I updated the code on GitHub. I tried to follow Ruby Style Guide (I couldn't read it all yet, so it might still be a little off) and break the code in more classes. Updating the code in the same question seems to be against the rules, so tell me if you think the code could use some more editing and I'll write another question for some further feedback!

Comment: I also suggested an edit on your answer. When I tried using the `do ... end` block in the icons array method it would return an error. Since it's an assignment I think the block wasn't necessary (or allowed).

Comment: @IanC fixed! It should be `begin..end`! :/ Post a link to your new question here when you're ready and I'll have a look when I get time.

Comment: After fixing the things you told me about on the code, I thought maybe it would be more helpful to start another one taking your suggestions into consideration since the beginning. I made an Asteroids remake and just posted a question on it [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148356/ruby-asteroids-remake). If you find some free time and feel like taking a look. Thanks a lot for your help Damien!